# Entity Framework Linq Group by DateRange

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have an application that records page visits and I need to be able to query by day by week and by month, sample output of a table query is as follows (each row represents a visit:

Visits result set

```
DateTimeLanding | PageViews
2016-05-12      | 2
2016-05-16      | 3
2016-05-16      | 8
2016-05-16      | 3
2016-05-17      | 7
2016-05-19      | 4
2016-05-28      | 6
2016-05-28      | 3
2016-05-30      | 1
```

If I want to query this result set for daily visits I do this:

```
var visitData = visits.GroupBy(v => v.DateLanding)
                            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                            .Select(g => new { From = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

                    visitNodes.Num = visits.Count().ToString();
                    visitNodes.Nodes = visitData.Select(p => new ReferralTrafficNode()
                    {
                        MetricDateTimeFrom = p.From,
                        MetricDateTimeTo = p.From.AddDays(1),
                        Value = p.Count
                    }).ToList();
```

This works fine for daily visits as I can group date.

How can I group the result set into groups of 7 days to get weekly visit data?
Essentially I need to be able to group by a date range

Comment: In your sample, you have days 12, 16, 17 (btw 16 is repeating 3 times, as well as 28). If you want to group by 5 days, would days 12 and 16 be in the same group? So, the first group would be (12, 13, 14, 15, 16), the second (17, 18, 19, 20, 21)? How do I know the starting date for a group? Is it the first available date (e.g in you case 12)?

Comment: each row represents 1 visit by a user, so it is correct to show multiple enteries for each day. In reality there are hundreds of visits each day. a week starts on Sunday, and you work backwards to get from the earliest date to get the starting sunday for that week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your group by to this:

```
v => v.DateLanding.AddDays(-(int)v.DateLanding.DayOfWeek)
```

This should group by the Sunday of the week selected.

Comment: I must admit. I cant see how this works, although it does. if I am reading the code correctly, you are saying to group by the date - the number of days needed to bring you back to the previous sunday, so Group by last Sunday. So how does the code know to group for the week? why is it not just grouping the Sundays?

Comment: When you do a group by, you provide it an expression that is evaluated and grouped by for each record.  You could do this: `GroupBy(v => "a")` and all of your records would be grouped by a key of "a".  The key that is generated for the group is based on that group by expression, and all records that evaluate the same for that expression are put into that group.  Does that help clear it up?

Comment: Of course, that makes perfect sense when you think about it.